# How to construct unequal width histograms with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I would like to construct a histogram with unequal bins (intervals)..Matlab construct only histograms with equal bins as if it's a diagram..!!!

Please help me...thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
x = randn(100,1)*3;           %# some random data
e = [-10 -5 -3 -1 1 2 3 20];  %# edges of intervals:  e(i) <= x < end(i+1)
c = histc(x,e);               %# get count in each interval
bar(e, c, 'histc')            %# bar plot
set(gca, 'xlim',[e(1) e(end)])
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot...i used your solution to build a function for my context of study ..

Comment: Is there a way to make it such all bins have the same xsize no matter how big it actually is?

Comment: @useretothepowerof2pi: I dont understand, if you want equal-width bins just use the regular HIST function. The whole idea of the above code is that we want non-regular intervals of different width

Comment: I mean, I want the bins to be of unequal sizes, but for the graph width to be the same.

Comment: @useretothepowerof2pi: oh, perhaps you can just omit the "x" locations in the above call and use `bar(c, 'histc')` instead. Then you can customize the `XTickLabels` of the axis to place the correct labels yourself

Answer (score 5):

2 solutions:

1. Specify bin *centers* with the
   2nd argument to [hist](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html).
2. Specify bin *Edges* with with
   the 2nd argument to [histc](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html). This
   function takes some further
   processing since it does not
   generate the graph directly - follow
   the link for a usage example.

Answer (score 2):

You could build your own histogram tool to create a custom histogram as you like.

- Use histc to determine which bins
  each point falls inside.
- Then use accumarray to count the number of elements in each bin.
- Then use bar to draw bars of your chosen widths. Or simply create
  patches of the given sizes. Use patch
  for that.

Or more simply, just use hist.

```
hist(rand(1000,1),[0 .1 .3 .6 1])
```