# equivalent to MatLab "bar" function in R?

Tags: r, matlab, ggplot2, package

Is there an function in R that does the same job as Matlab's "[bar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html)" function?

R does have a "barplot" function in the library graphics, however, it is not the same.

The Matlab bar(X,Y) (verbatim excerpt from MATLAB [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bar.html)) "draws a bar for each element in Y *at locations specified in X*, where X is a vector defining the x-axis intervals for the vertical bars." (emphasis mine)

However, the R barplot function does not allow one to specify locations.

Perhaps there is a method in ggplot2 that supports this? I am only able to find standard bar charts in ggplot2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `barplot` is not the same as bar, but you should read the whole help.  You can do many things to position the bars.  The first is simply their order in Y.  You could insert spaces if you wish (additional 0s).  If you have X and Y then sort Y on X (`Y[order(X)]`) and plot it.  If you need to change positions use the "space" and "width" arguments.  It's not as straightforward as specifying X values I suppose but it's definitely more useful in most situations.  Generally what you want to adjust is widths of bars and spaces between bars.  Their position on the X-axis should be arbitrary.  If the position on the X-axis is really meaningful then you should be using line plots, not bar graphs.

Answer (score 4):

In R:

```
barplot(rbind(1:10, 2:11), beside=T, names.arg=1:10)
```

[image]

In MATLAB:

```
>> bar(1:10, [(1:10)' (2:11)'])
```

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question. The special case I am referring to is where specific widths are associated with each bin.

Comment: @QuantGuy The question was ambiguous, and this is certainly one common interpretation. It would have been helpful it you made the question clearer by providing some example code/figure.

Comment: Hear, hear. And what on earth does it mean to say "the R barplot function does not allow one to specify locations"?

Comment: @DWin meaning that the coordinate of the bar is specified by a vector (as opposed to a generic sequence of numbers). I linked directly to the Matlab code which uses exactly this language.

Comment: @JohnColby - I appreciate the help. Agreed, the language could certainly be clearer. Thanks!

Comment: @DWin: I think OP means something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379230/how-to-construct-unequal-width-histograms-with-matlab/2381373#2381373

Answer (score 2):

Read up on `par` .  Then observe, for example:

```
x<-c(1,2,4,5,6) 
y<-c(3,4,3,4,2) 
plot(x,y,type='h',lwd=6)
```

Edit: yes, I know this doesn't (yet) plot multiple data sets, but I would hope you can see simple ways to make that happen, with spacings, colors, etc. specified to your exact liking :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds vaguely like the R `stepfun`. On the other hand one would need to know what "draws a bar" means before saying it is not the same as `barplot(..., horiz=TRUE)` One would, of course, need to examine some more detailed evidence such as data and plots before arriving at a conclusion, however.  @John Colby should be congratulated for adding some specificity to the discussion. The axis function is probably what Quant Guy needs education regarding.