# How to plot a bar graph with different colors and groups in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot a bar graph which summarizes algorithms performance. It has three main parameters

1. Publication year (the x axis)
2. Data type (bar color)
3. Algorithm score ( bar height)

Here is an example data:

```
dtypes = {'type1','type2','type3'}; %All of the possible data types
methods_name = {'method1','method2','method3'};
methods_accuracy = [89.2, 95.54, 85];
methods_year = [2016, 2017, 2016] ;
methods_dtype = {'type1', 'type2', 'type2'};
```

Here I wish to get 3 bars, 2 of which in the year 2016 with different colors and one in 2017 with a color matching to one from 2016.

For some reason, I can't seem to do what I want using the `bar` function. It seems simple but I think I am missing something regarding how this function works.
using

```
bar(methods_year, methods_accuracy)
```

gives an error :

```
XData cannot contain duplicate values.
```

Comment: I got to solve the task including possible collisions but at price of variable distance between bars in group and between groups. Is that OK?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. It is ok not to have the same distance between the year groups. Within each year group, it is desired to have equal spacing between bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing multiple bars per category seems to be commonly done by using a matrix. Based on your comment this doesn't seem possible. It also seems that the `bar()` function cannot accept a vector of colors. The following code should be more general and allow you to specify the bar colors based on your 'types'.

I have modified code available at on the MATLAB Answers forum (https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/310039-how-to-change-the-color-of-individual-bars-in-a-bar-chart) to account for your type of data and processing the data into the correct format.

[image]

```
% code modified from https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/310039-how-to-change-the-color-of-individual-bars-in-a-bar-chart

% Plots a bar chart and gives a different color to each bar.
% Also plots the value of the bar above the bar.
clc;    % Clear the command window.
close all;  % Close all figures (except those of imtool.)
clear;  % Erase all existing variables.
workspace;  % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
fontSize = 10;
format compact

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% your data here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
dtypes = {'type1','type2','type3'}; %All of the possible data types
methods_name = {'method1','method2','method3'};
methods_accuracy = [89.2, 95.54, 85];
methods_year = [2016, 2017, 2016] ;
methods_dtype = {'type1', 'type2', 'type2'};

% sorting all vectors into values
[sort_yrs,inds] = sort(methods_year);
sort_methods = methods_name(inds);
sort_dtype = methods_dtype(inds);
sort_accuracy = methods_accuracy(inds);
colors = zeros([length(sort_methods),3]);
colors_types = [[1,0,0];[0,1,0];[0,0,1]];

for i = 1:1:length(dtypes)
    ind1 = strfind(sort_dtype, dtypes{i});
    ind2 = find(not(cellfun('isempty', ind1)));
    for j = 1:1:length(ind2)
        colors(ind2(j),:) = colors_types(i,:);
    end
end
%%%%%%%%%%% end of processing data %%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% plotting all bars in a loop
for b = 1 : length(sort_accuracy)

    % plot a single bar
    handlebar(b) = bar(b, sort_accuracy(b), 'BarWidth', 0.9);

    % assigning color to bar
    set(handlebar(b), 'FaceColor', colors(b,:));
    hold on;
end

% title and axis labels, if desired
title('A title Here', 'FontSize', fontSize);
xlabel('x', 'FontSize', fontSize);
ylabel('y', 'FontSize', fontSize);

% finding locations for tick labels for years, if desired
temp = histc(sort_yrs,unique(sort_yrs));
% locations to use if at the middle of the year
xTickLocs = cumsum(temp) - 0.5*temp;
% locations to use if at the beginning of the year
%xTickLocs = cumsum(temp) - 0.5*temp(1);

xticks(xTickLocs);
xticklabels(unique(sort_yrs));
% addind labels
set(gca, 'XTickLabels', xticklabels);
```

Comment: I see what you did but there is a problem when you have a specific year that has two methods with the same type? (which is very possible)

Comment: you could plot two smaller bars at the same year with two different colors. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379230/how-to-construct-unequal-width-histograms-with-matlab) could help

Comment: @itzikBenShabat, I think that this new code will be more general and will get a result close to your goal.